# Dynamically add query parameters without value to Retrofit request

Tags: url, retrofit, square-bracket

I have request that set list of services that are turned on for user.

Request has following format:

https://myserver.com/setservices?param1=val1&param2=val2&service[10]&service[1000]&service[10000]

List of service parameters ("service[10]&service[1000]&service[10000]") is created dynamically and each parameter doesn't have value. Is it possible to achive this using Retrofit?

Comment: You can use Query parameter like that [please check it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641609/8471798)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [retrofit documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/):

> For complex query parameter combinations a `Map` can be used.

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

I guess this will make what you want to achieve.

Comment: @QueryMap doesn't allow to include query parameters without value. From documentation: "Values are URL encoded and null will not include the query parameter in the URL"

Comment: What about empty strings?

Comment: It produces URL with equality symbols:
https://myserver.com/setservices?service[100]=&service[10000]=&service[10]=
But server understands it fine.

Answer (score 6):

I found workaround how to do this.

```
@GET("/setservices{services_query}")
ServicesSetResponse setServices(@EncodedPath("services_query") String servicesQuery);
```

And then:

```
getService().setServices("?param1=val1&param2=val2" + "&services[10]&services[100000]&services[1000000]")
```

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore? `EncodedPath` and if you use `Path` it complains and forces you to use `Query`

Comment: not working now :C

Answer (score 4):

We can pass using the @QueryMap as below:

```
GET("/movies")
Call<List<Movies>> getMovies(
    @QueryMap Map<String, String> options
);
```

To build the parameters:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("director", "Haresh");
data.put("page", String.valueOf(2));
```

It will generate the Url like:

http://your.api.url/movies?page=2&director=Haresh